# Agregar elementos a un arreglo de Objetos

Tags: array, poo, typescript, object, jsonarray

¿Como agrego elementos a un arreglo de objetos en Typescript? De acuerdo a lo que yo creo debería ser de la siguiente forma pero por alguna razón no funciona.

***OBJETO***

```
conSubNet: Port[] = [{
    ip: '',
    pu: '',
    uu: '',
    bc: '',
    mm: '',
    host: '',
    reqHost: ''
}];
```

***LINEA DONDE AGREGO UN DATO***

```
this.conSubNet[z].ip = this.octOne + ' . ' + this.octTwo + ' . ' + this.octThree + ' . ' + this.octFour;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No funciona porque

```
this.conSubNet[z]
```

*Selecciona* el elemento existente en el índice `z`. Si dicho índice no existe, devuelve `undefined`. Y `undefined` **no es un objeto** y no soporta el acceso a sus elementos internos usando `.`.

La solución es **asignar un objeto** a la posición `[z]`. Cambia tu asignación a

```
this.conSubNet[z] = { ip: this.octOne + ' . ' + this.octTwo + ' . ' + this.octThree + ' . ' + this.octFour };
```

Observa que, en caso de que **ya exista un elemento en esa posición**, ese código **reemplaza** dicho elemento. Si no tienes la seguridad de que el *array* esté vacío, deberías comprobarlo primero:

```
if( this.conSubNet[x] === undefined ) {
    this.conSubNet[z] = { ip: this.octOne + ' . ' + this.octTwo + ' . ' + this.octThree + ' . ' + this.octFour };
} else {
    this.conSubNet[z].ip = this.octOne + ' . ' + this.octTwo + ' . ' + this.octThree + ' . ' + this.octFour;
}
```

Comment: Gracias me sirvió completamente amigo, realmente era más sencillo de lo que pensaba y gracias a todos los detalles que mencionaste me quedaron más claro algunos puntos de los objetos 

Comment: @ASASCED El código que te he puesto **añade** o **reemplaza** si ya hubiera un elemento en el índice. Salvo que estés creando el *array* desde 0, deberías comprobar primero si ya existe algo en esa posición.

Comment: gracias y si el arreglo se inicia desde 0 así que no hay nada que comprobar pero más adelante ocuparé comprobarlo como mencionas ya que agregaré más datos en otras secciones.

Comment: @ASASCED Respuesta editada para que compruebe si ya hay un elemento :-)

Comment: gracias eso me será de mucha ayuda 